# How to combine fuzzy search and field boosting

Tags: search, zend-framework, syntax, lucene

I'm developing a Lucene search for my Zend 1.12 site. I would like to combine fuzzy search and field boosting. I try syntax like

```
title:"query"^10~0.8 OR description:"query"~0.8
```

It seems not to change results. I've also tried to find hints on the Internet, nobody had similar problem. This is query for particular setting and field boosting cannot be set in advance.

The question is: does Lucene support such a combination of modifiers? Is this syntax correct?

Comment: have you tried doing the fuzzy first, then boosting it?  `title:query~0.8 ^10 OR description:query~0.8` (no quotes-- `~` outside of quotes treats the term like a phrase, resulting in a proximity search rather than a fuzzy search. http://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html)